# Bcrypt ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

Hi im new to Bcrypt in rails, i was wondering on how to use this gem correctly, as of now i was able to make the password hashed but when comparing it to the user input for the password it does not match.

here is my code for the Encryption and login.

```
def self.login(user)
    hashed_password = encrypt_password(user["password"])
    result = User.where({:username => user["username"], :password => hashed_password})
    return result
end

def self.add_user(user)
    hashed_password = encrypt_password(user["password"])
    result = User.create({:username => user["username"],
        :password => hashed_password,
        :firstname => user["firstname"],
        :middle_initial => user["middle_initial"],
        :lastname => user["lastname"],
        :advisory_class => user["advisory_class"]})
    return result
end

def self.encrypt_password(password)
    password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)
end
```

In the add_user i was encrypting it using the encrypt_password function, when logging in using the login function. the password does not match with the password ecrypted in the databases. im sure im not doing this the right way, can you pin point where am i doing it wrong. thanks.

Comment: As a note, the hash braces can be omitted in calls of the form `x({...})` as they're implicit in Ruby. For example: `User.create(:username => user['username'], ...)` or even better `User.create(username: user['username'], ...)` using the modern hash notation.

Comment: Thank you for the note, but that's not my primary concern for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick here is that [BCrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) creates a different result each time you run it with the same password by design. This makes the output of the function extremely unpredictable so it's not practical to brute-force guess passwords.

The way you verify is:

```
hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create(user['password'])
```

The way you verify is:

```
if @user = User.where(username: user['username'])
  # User found

  if BCrypt::Password.new(@user.password) == user['password']
    # Success!
  else
    # Invalid password
  end
else
  # User not found
end
```

This works because the `==` method is overridden for the Password object. It's not doing a literal string comparison.

Comment: I've changed my login funciton to this.

 def self.login(user)
  result = false
  hashed_password = encrypt_password(user["password"])
  user = User.where({:username => user["username"]})
  if BCrypt::Password.new(hashed_password) == user[0].password
   result = true
  end
  return result
 end

and gives the result of invalid hash. what does that mean?

Comment: I've had to make an edit here because I confused `user` and `user`.